# Why do I need to use fopen twice in matlab for reading an image?

Tags: image, matlab, fopen

I am trying to open an image using fopen command. I have to use this command twice for getting it working. Why is it so? Here is my code:

```
  fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
  opened = fopen(fid);
  figure,imshow(opened);
```

Comment: why not use `imread`, assuming you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `imread` doesn't even need the toolbox - it's a core function along with things like `imagesc`.

Answer (score 3):

The second call just gets the full path of the filename of the file which was previously opened.  From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html)

> `filename = fopen(fileID)` returns the file name that a previous call to `fopen` used when it opened the file specified by `fileID`. The output filename is resolved to the full path. The `fopen` function does not read information from the file to determine the output value.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` does not read data in.  It merely opens the file so that MATLAB can read from (or write to) it. You would then use functions like `fgets` or `textscan` to read the data in the appropriate format. It is not normally used for image files (unless you're doing something with them other than reading in the data for display or processing).

In fact in the given code no reading in of your file is happening until the line `imshow(opened)`.  Since `opened` is a filename as explained in Adam's answer, `imshow` reads it in and then displays it.  However, it's not stored in a workspace variable.  As mentioned in the comments , you should use `imread` for image files:

```
I = imread(filename);
figure; imshow(I);
```